# XML migration body field process plugin

Tags: 8, migrations

I have my migrations pulling in my field data. However, I cannot figure out how to get the text_format set in my YML file so the HTML doesn't show up on import. I have my content type body text format set to full_html, yet on import if is basic_html.

Here is my YML parts:

```
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  urls: 'http://location.to.xml/node/00000/xml'
  data_parser_plugin: simple_xml

fields:
  -
    name: body
    label: body
    selector: content:encoded 

process:
  'body/format':
    plugin: stripouthtml
    default_value: full_html
  'body/value': content

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_value: news
```

I think it is the process part I need help understanding. I have tried a few different ways. I just cannot find anything that has worked or should work.

Comment: What does the `stripouthtml` plugin? I mean I've a Drupal site with migrate_plus and migrate_tools I don't see that process plugin, neither in core.

Comment: my bad, i left that in testing something else. it should be 'plugin: default_value' with that is still comes through as <p> content </p>

Comment: Ok so your format is getting 'full_html' as value? Could you check that you have that filter format in here `/admin/config/content/formats`? Because seems to me that perphaps you have another filter format. Also take in mind that filter formats "process" field value and strip fix HTML so can break your output if no taken into account.

Comment: In the website I am importing into, yes I have a full_html format. Permissions are admin and authorized. The format that the content is coming from is 'limited_html'. Does that matter?